# Triangle not displaying

Tags: opengl

I am trying to display a triangle with the below code. The shaders I am using are very basic and just basically output the colour white. I cannot see where the error is.

```
void init( void ){

glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

vec4 vertexPositions[] =
{
    0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

GLuint positionBufferObject;

glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader23.glsl", "fshader23.glsl" );
glUseProgram( program );

GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);

// tell openGL how to interpret the array of data stored in buffer
// this implicitly refers to the buffer currently bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}

void display( void )
{
// clears the window, sets color to glClearColor()
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

// rendering function
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glFlush();
}
```

Comment: Nothing is shown because you do not draw anything. You have to call glDrawArrays after setting up the buffers.

Comment: My apologies, I neglected to include the display() function. I have added in to the code

Comment: Two minor things:1) Is vec4 a typedef for GL_FLOAT? When not, the sizeof operator might not return what you expect. The result should be 48.  2) The first argument of glVertexAttribPointer has to have the same value as the one sent to glEnableVertexAttribArray. Most probably this holds because vPosition got 0 assigned automatically.

Comment: Maybe your triangle is invisible or it is black (and background also black). Try to swap vertexPositions[0] and vertexPositions[1].

Comment: Thanks for the replies. vec 4 is a GL_FLOAT. I have tried changing the value of glVertexAttribPointer and unfortunately I still have no display. I do apologise as I have read up as much on the subject as I can, yet my understanding of it all is still limited

Comment: check out whether the  `vPosition` is matching `location = 0`

Comment: defining `vec4` as `GL_FLOAT` is so confusing. Also replace `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);` with `glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);` as the first parameter should be vertex attribute index.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions and help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear thedepth buffer also before drawing the triangle with following statements:

```
glClearColor(19.0f / 255.0f, 9.0f / 255.0f, 99.0f / 255.0f, 1.0f);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I compiled the code, and it is working now. You can find my code [Here](https://github.com/mmostajab/TriangleRendering/tree/master)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help :) Everything is working as intended.